# Is it correct to say that a decaying oscillation goes to zero?

Tags: limits

Let's say we have a function $f(x)= e^{-2x} (sin(x)+ cos(x))$, and we want to describe its behavior as $x \to \infty$ . We know that this function is a decaying oscillation, but is it mathematically correct to say that as $x \to \infty ,  f \to 0$ ? I think it is wrong to say this because the limit as $x \to \infty$ does not exist, (the function oscillates and does not remain above/below the x-axis).

Comment: $f\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$ simply implies that $f$ gets arbitrary close to 0 for large enough $x$

Comment: The limit does exist. This is perhaps easiest to see via the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Take a look at the graph of this particular function: the function is decreasing on $\mathbb R^+$. But even if is keeps oscillating like $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ it's still correct to say that $\lim_{x\to +\infty}\dfrac{\sin{x}}{x}=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is correct to say that $$f(x)= e^{-2x} (sin(x)+ cos(x))$$ approaches to $0$ as $x\to \infty.$

It is mathematically correct because $$|e^{-2x} (sin(x)+ cos(x))| \le 2 e^{-2x} \to 0$$

Answer (score 0):

It is correct to say as $x \to \infty$ that $f \to 0$, because we can squeeze the function $f(x)= e^{-2x} (sin(x)+ cos(x))$ using the two functions $2e^{-2x}$ and $-2e^{-2x}$, and since the limit of both $2e^{-2x}$ and $-2e^{-2x}$ as $x \to \infty$ is 0, then the squeeze theorem says that the limit of $e^{-2x} (sin(x)+ cos(x))$ as $x \to \infty$ is 0.